# How count string variations as single one in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list with multiple names and multiple variations of the same name of companies.
How to count the same names as one in python 3.x?

This code:

```
my_list = ['Telecom.uk', 'Telecom ltd', 'Telecom Ltd.', 'Vodafone Ltd.', 'Vodafone Ltd']
results = {}
for value in my_list:
    results[value] = my_list.count(value)
print(results)
```

returns:

```
{'Telecom.uk': 1, 'Telecom ltd': 1, 'Telecom Ltd.': 1, 'Vodafone Ltd.': 1, 'Vodafone Ltd': 1}
```

How to iterate over the items and find similarities so they can be count as one like this?

```
{'Telecom': 3, 'Vodafone: 2}
```

Comment: Are you looking only these two companies/a small list of companies with distinct names? Are you looking for something more extensible? Please specify what possible inputs you can have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we have a function `remove_extra(name)` it removes the extra stuff from name. It replaces dot '.' by blank space' ' then splits it and selects first item i.e just the main name needed.
Later we map my_list with remove_extra to get clean names then we count it as you initially did.

```
def remove_extra(name):
    return name.replace('.',' ').split()[0]
my_list = ['Telecom.uk', 'Telecom ltd', 'Telecom Ltd.', 'Vodafone Ltd.', 'Vodafone Ltd']
my_list=list(map(remove_extra,my_list))
results = {}
for value in my_list:
    results[value] = my_list.count(value)
print(results)
```